# Adding custom templates to 3rd party Django app

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to customize the appearance of the [django-user-sessions](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-user-sessions) package for my Django project.  When I load the /account/sessions/ page, which lists the user's current sessions, I get the following message:

```
Provide a template named user_sessions/_base.html to style this page and remove this message.
```

I found a [question that dealt with this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445532/integrating-third-party-django-apps-and-templates) for earlier versions of Django but I couldn't get it to work for 1.8.  Where do I put the **_base.html** template for it to be detected?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make folder user_sessions inside root directory.

```
project_name
   app1
   templates
      user_sessions
          _base.html
   manage.py
```

Try this and let me know.

Comment: Didn't work for me, so I just replicated the app into my project and modified it as necessary.

Comment: It should work, Please check spelling of folder name. Write here your project structure.

Comment: @john, if this answer is helpfulo for you, then accept this answer by clicking on right mark symbol, Thanks